# Writing large binary data to file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, huffman-code

Hi I am working on a project on writing our own huffman coding. I am currently having trouble writing the binary 1's and 0's to an output file. It works with smaller input files but for very large files it does not write anything out to the output file. The method responsible for writing is the `compress` method. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
package proj3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Project3 {

//variables for PriorityQueue and Huffman Tree
private static PriorityQueue<BinaryNode<Character>> queue;
private static BinaryNode<Character> huffTree;
private static Map<Character, String> table = new LinkedHashMap<Character, String>();

/**
 * Method for creating Huffman Tree
 * @param counts Map that contains all characters and their frequencies
 * @return the Huffman Tree
 */
public static BinaryNode<Character> makeTree(Map<Character, Integer> counts)
{
    queue = new PriorityQueue<BinaryNode<Character>>();

    for(Character c : counts.keySet())
    {
        BinaryNode<Character> tree = new BinaryNode<Character>(c, counts.get(c), null, null);
        queue.add(tree);
    }

    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        if(queue.size() >= 2)
        {   
            BinaryNode<Character> n1 = queue.remove();
            BinaryNode<Character> n2 = queue.remove();
            Integer weight = n1.getFreq() + n2.getFreq();
            huffTree = new BinaryNode<Character>(null, weight, n1, n2);
            queue.add(huffTree);
        }
        if(queue.size() == 1)
        {
            return queue.remove();
        }
    }
    return huffTree;
}

public static void encode(BinaryNode<Character> node, String s)
{
    if(!node.isLeaf())
    {
        encode(node.getLeft(), s + "0");
        encode(node.getRight(), s + "1");
    }
    else
    {
        table.put(node.getElement(), s);
    }
}

public static void compress(String in, String out) throws IOException
{
    try 
    {
        File outFile = new File(out);
        FileOutputStream compressedFile = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(in));
        while(infile.hasNext())
        {
            infile.useDelimiter("");
            String str = infile.next();
            Character character = str.charAt(0);
            for(Character c : table.keySet())
            {
                if(c == character){
                    compressedFile.write(table.get(c).getBytes());
                    compressedFile.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        for(Byte b : table.get('^').getBytes())
        {
            compressedFile.write(b);
        }
        infile.close();
        compressedFile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void decompress(String s)
{

}

public static void printEncodings(Map<Character, String> m)
{
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();

    System.out.println("Character Encodings");
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    for(Character c : m.keySet())
    {
        chars.add(c);
        Collections.sort(chars);
    }
    for(Character c : chars)
    {
        System.out.print(c + "\t" + m.get(c) + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total Characters: " + chars.size());
}

/**
 * Method for creating map with character and its frequencies
 * @param s the file name to be opened
 * @return the Map containing characters and frequencies
 */
public static Map<Character, Integer> charCount(String s){

    Map<Character, Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();

    try {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(s));
        while(file.hasNext()){
            file.useDelimiter("");
            String str = file.next();
            Character c = str.charAt(0);
            if(counts.containsKey(c)){
                counts.put(c, counts.get(c) + 1);
            }
            else{
                counts.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        counts.put('^', 1);
        System.out.println("Character Frequencies");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        for(Character c : counts.keySet())
        {
            chars.add(c);
            Collections.sort(chars);
        }
        for(Character c : chars){
            System.out.println(c + "\t" + counts.get(c));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total characters: " + chars.size() + "\n");
        file.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return counts;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    if(args.length != 3)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of arguments.");
    }
    encode(makeTree(charCount(args[0])), "");
    printEncodings(table);
    try {
        compress(args[0], args[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Does the program finish? Have you stepped through the program to see what it does?

Comment: yes it prints out all the correct character frequencies and encoding table

Comment: is it empty file when large data written?

Comment: Yes when I try to compress a large file such as "Alice in Wonderland" book and write the binary to a file, it writes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're facing a performance/memory problem in the compress() method. The encodings get printed alright in your main method, but I believe the file output will get stuck. I can see at least three possibilities for optimization in your code:

1. You're using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the input file char by char, but you don't use any parsing capabilities offered by Scanner. Try using an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) instead.
2. You're looping over the set of keys in the Huffman table and checking for equality. You can simply use the current char to get the String it is mapped to and omit the loop.
3. You don't need to loop the byte array to write it to the output file. The write() method of [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29) can take a whole byte array as parameter.

With my humble Java skills, I'd rather implement it somehow like below; please note that this is **untested code** since I don't have your BinaryNode class:

```
public static void compress(String in, String out) throws IOException
{
    try 
        {
            File outFile = new File(out);
            FileOutputStream compressedFile = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            // 1. Use a Reader instead of a Scanner;
            // make sure to use the correct charset
            FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(in);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis,        
                Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

            // use BufferedReader for even better performance
            Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            int r;
            while ((r = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                char ch= (char) r;

                // 2. Get the string for this character directly instead of
                // looping the keySet and checking for equivalence
                String s= table.get(ch);
                if (s != null) {
                    // 3. Write entire array of bytes instead of 
                    // looping and writing bytes one by one
                    compressedFile.write(s.getBytes());
                }
            }
            fis.close();
            compressedFile.close();
        }
    ...
```

Comment: I swear I have have put in exactly what you have written but it still doesn't work.....Is it possible that other parts of my code is so inefficient that it isn't working for large files?

Comment: I think not, the rest should be sufficiently efficient. Please check the following: 1) You're throwing when args.length != 3, but only using 2 args in your code. 2) Does args[0] point to an existing file? Do all the directories in args[1] exist? 3) Did you clean/recompile the project after doing modifications to the code? 4) Does BinaryNode implement java.lang.comparable (necessary for PriorityQueue)? 5) Did you run your code in debug mode and check any logs or console outputs for errors/stack traces? 6) Does the output file get written with 0 KB or is it missing? 7) Does your code terminate?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you need to call `compressedFile.flush()`

Improve it like this

```
            if(c == character){
                compressedFile.write(table.get(c).getBytes());
                compressedFile.flush();
            }
```

---

Additionally consider using `try/catch`. Will improve the integrity of the implementation.

Comment: No sorry it still does not write anything :(

Comment: Sorry again but I'm sure I updated exactly as you wrote but it's still not working....